# Switching language in multilingual Joomla don't remember for next time

Tags: php, joomla, multilingual

I have created a multilingual website in Joomla for several locality. every thing is OK and before i create multilingual website and that work as well. But at this time, When language switched to another language with going to another page or reload the website again the last switched language don't load and default language load. For example if i click on Deutsch language and switch to it the url create as this:

```
http://www.test.com/index.php/de/
```

After going to another link in the website again english load or if i reload the website with this link:

```
http://www.test.com/
```

The url again generated for english like on:

```
http://www.test.com/index.php/en/
```

I check every thing and a lot of searching in internet but i can't fix this. I use Joomla 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

You should check the language switcher module configuration and make sure the language plugins are published. 
Also you may want to take a look to http://www.neno-translate.com , it provides these features with a few clicks.